How to create push notification with long text and picture in one style
How to create push notification
with long text and picture in one notification style?
I'm using BigTextStyle for showing push notification,
because I need to show big text, but how can I add an image ?
Or I need to use some custom notifications?
some example:


I hope this help you. Let me know if you found difficulties in this
private fun showBigNotification(
    bitmap: Bitmap,
    mBuilder: NotificationCompat.Builder,
    icon: Int,
    title: String,
    message: String,
    resultPendingIntent: PendingIntent,
    alarmSound: Uri
) {


    val CHANNEL_ID = "123456789"
    val name: CharSequence = mContext.getString(R.string.app_name)
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    val inboxStyle = NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
    val notificationManager =
        mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
        .build()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") val mChannel =
            NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance)
        mChannel.setSound(alarmSound, audioAttributes)
        mChannel.enableLights(true)
        mChannel.enableVibration(true)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
    }


    val bigPictureStyle = NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
    bigPictureStyle.setBigContentTitle(title)
    bigPictureStyle.setSummaryText(Html.fromHtml(message).toString())
    bigPictureStyle.bigPicture(getResizedBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.width))
    val notification: Notification
    val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(
        mContext, CHANNEL_ID
    )/*
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
        */
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
        .setSound(alarmSound)
        .setStyle(bigPictureStyle)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.resources, icon))
        .setContentText(message)

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
        notificationBuilder.color = mContext.resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
    } else {
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon)
    }
    val id = Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextInt(1000)
    notificationManager.notify(id, notificationBuilder.build())

}


I think this will help: Create an inbox-style notification.
Here, they're using InboxStyle for the long content and setLargeIcon on NotificationCompat.Builder for the large icon.
Like this:
val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.baseline_email_24)
        .setContentTitle("[Title]")
        .setContentText("[Content]")
        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.logo))
        .setStyle(
                NotificationCompat.InboxStyle()
                .addLine("[Your text]")
        )
        .build()

In the code above,

Replace BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.logo) for .setLargeIcon() with your image resource.
Replace [Your text] for .addLine() with the text you want to show.

And if anyhow this does not fulfill your requirement then, I think you'll have to implement a custom notification for that.

This should be a comment in its current state, not an answer. Link-only solutions are not allowed on Stack Overflow; instead, add the relevant content from the link to the answer itself.
